# execute function after dispatch in another component in my react native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

i wanna to run  function after i dispatch sth in another componnent (promise is not my solution) 
for example i want to dispatch THIS in COMPONENT 1 and then execute function in Component whiche is   responsible to start  animated object

Answer (score 0):

A solution with redux is the use `mapStateToProps` to listen to the change on the store.

Example:
`userState = {isLoggedIn: false}`

A - dispatch a loginSuccessAction

B - Change the user in the reducer and set it as ```LoggedIn: true````

C - mapStateToProps with isLoggedIn

D - Change Whatever you want in the listening component

---

`

```
// Action
const loginSuccess = {type: loginSuccess }

//

//Reducer 
export function reducer( state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type) {
      case loginSuccess.type: {
          return {
            ...state,
            isFetching: false,
            isLoggedIn: true,
            errorMessage: '',
          };
       }
       case logoutRequest.type: {
           return initialState;
        }
        default:
            return state;
        }
    }
}

// MapStatetoPros Other Component listening to isLoggedIn
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.user.isLoggedIn,
    };
}

// When props change other component
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props !== nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            isLoggedIn: nextProps.isLoggedIn,
        });
    }
}
```

`